# How to export a datagrid to Excel file in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, export-to-excel

How do I export data in my datagrid to an [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) file in [Flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flex)?

Can anyone provide some examples for that? I am browsing but couldn't find out a single example of that kind.

**EDIT**

Browsed a lot and found out how to convert datagrid data to csv format. Now How to convert that to excel? Is there a way to do that without using any server script ? Can't it be done in Flex alone?

Comment: What's your server-side technology?

Comment: using java Servlets in eclipse

Answer (score 3):

There is [as3xls](http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/) for you to [write xls file](http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/wiki/Tutorial#Writing). It only support a single sheet(but I think that's fine).

But I think using csv or html as stated by @susichan and @Rafal Ziolkowski will be more simple if you do not need to use excel functions (like cell formula).

Oh, and there is [csvlib](http://code.google.com/p/csvlib/) for writing csv. For html, do it like writing XML will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Excel reads the [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) table as a kind of spreadsheet. Just read the grid row by row, column by column and produce a set of HTML table cells and produce a file named whatever.xls.

Comment: I have created it in the form of html tables. How to produce an excel file?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Java servlet back-end you can use a servlet to output the file.

My only [Flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flex)-only idea was to output the [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) data to a popup with a textarea that could be copied and pasted into a file by the user.

Answer (score 1):

First Download swc file from the following Link

[Link](http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/downloads/detail?name=as3xls-1.0.swc)

Now you need to do little bit of work just copy that code and give column names appropriately.

```
public function roExport_export_Result(e:ResultEvent):void
        {
            if(e.result.length != 0)
            {
                btnExportToExcel.enabled = true;

                var arrExportResult:Array = e.result as Array;

                xlsFile = new ExcelFile();
                var sheet:Sheet = new Sheet();

                sheet.resize(arrExportResult.length+1,14);

                sheet.setCell(0,0,'Id');
                sheet.setCell(0,1,'Full Name');
                sheet.setCell(0,2,'Gender');
                sheet.setCell(0,3,'Birth Date');
                sheet.setCell(0,4,'College Name');
                sheet.setCell(0,5,'Qualification');
                sheet.setCell(0,6,'Email Id');
                sheet.setCell(0,7,'Mobile');
                sheet.setCell(0,8,'Position Applied For');
                sheet.setCell(0,9,'Technology Interested');
                sheet.setCell(0,10,'User Name');
                sheet.setCell(0,11,'Password');
                sheet.setCell(0,12,'Exam Date');
                sheet.setCell(0,13,'Percentage');
                sheet.setCell(0,14,'IsActive');

                for(var i:int=0;i<arrExportResult.length;i++)
                {
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 0, arrExportResult[i].Id);
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 1, arrExportResult[i].FullName);
                    if(arrExportResult[i].Gender == 1)
                    {
                        arrExportResult[i].Gender = "Male"
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arrExportResult[i].Gender = "Female";
                    }
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 2, arrExportResult[i].Gender);
                    var date:String = arrExportResult[i].BirthDate.date.toString();
                    var month:String = (arrExportResult[i].BirthDate.month + 1).toString();
                    var year:String = arrExportResult[i].BirthDate.fullYear.toString();
                    var bDate:String = date + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                    arrExportResult[i].BirthDate = bDate;
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 3, arrExportResult[i].BirthDate);
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 4, arrExportResult[i].CollegeId);
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 5, arrExportResult[i].QualificationId);
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 6, arrExportResult[i].EmailId);
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 7, arrExportResult[i].Mobile);
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 8, arrExportResult[i].PositionName);
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 9, arrExportResult[i].TechForTraining);
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 10, arrExportResult[i].UserName);
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 11, arrExportResult[i].Password);
                    var date:String = arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate.date.toString();
                    var month:String = (arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate.month + 1).toString();
                    var year:String = arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate.fullYear.toString();
                    var hour:String = arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate.hours.toString();
                    var min:String = arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate.minutes.toString();
                    var sec:String = arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate.seconds.toString();
                    var cDate:String = date + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
                    arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate = cDate;
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 12, arrExportResult[i].CreatedDate);
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 13, arrExportResult[i].Percentage);
                    sheet.setCell(i+1, 14, arrExportResult[i].IsActive);
                }

                dataGridResult.dataProvider = arrExportResult;

                xlsFile.sheets.addItem(sheet);      
                bytes = xlsFile.saveToByteArray();                  
            }
            else
            {
                arrExportResult = new Array();
                dataGridResult.dataProvider = arrExportResult;
                btnExportToExcel.enabled = false;
                xlsFile = new ExcelFile();
                var sheet:Sheet = new Sheet();
                Alert.show("No Records Found",parentApplication.alertTitle);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer

http://learnflexair.wordpress.com/category/uncategorized/air/

Comment: it is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

as3xls seems to read fine but writing Excel files is another story.  It can't write multisheet workbooks, it [most of the time] can't read it's own files, and when Excel can read what as3xls spits out you have to do multiple saves to get all the garbage out.  A real bummer.  I'm working on using AIR 2.0's NativeProcess to call a Python script to do the writing and I guess I'll have to export the datagrid/ArrayCollection to CSV first... seems like a long way around.  Can't believe there's not a better ActionScript option for mucking with Excel.  Is it really that rare of a task?